# When is a 5x40mm confirmat screw appropriate compared to the slightly larger 7x50mm screw?

Tags: screws

I'm thinking about getting some confirmat screws for 3/4" material. Should I get the 40mm or the 50mm variety?

Comment: What are you mounting the 3/4" material to?

Comment: It's just a box with 3/4" MDF screwing into the edge of another piece of 3/4" MDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this supplier](http://www.mcfeelys.com/confirmat-mdf-screws) 7x50 is for 3/4" materials and 5x40 is for 1/2" materials.